# what does *array mean in python

Tags: python

Below is the code:

```
> arrays=[['bar','bar','baz','baz','foo','foo','qux','qux'],['one','two','one','two','one','two','one','two']]
> zip(*arrays)
```

What does

> *arrays

mean in python?

Comment: An array is just a list. What you have is a two dimensional array which is pretty much lists insides of a list.

Comment: It means you are unpacking the arrary values with the asterisk (*) unpack means use all the values at once.